# Flask printing html to console instead of redirecting

Tags: python, flask

I have this flask code in an auth blueprint:

```
 @auth.route('/login/',methods=['POST','GET'])
 def login():
      email         = request.form.get('email',type=str)
      password      = request.form.get('password',type=str)

      error = None
      if email != None and password != None:
           if verify_user(email,password):
               user = next((item for item in app.config['AUTHORIZED'] if item["email"] == email), None)
               session['name'] = user['name']

               flash("welcome " + session['name'] + '!')
               return redirect(url_for('admin.show'))

           error = "invalid credentials" 

      return render_template('auth/index.html',error=error)
```

and the following in an admin blueprint, which I am redirecting to from the login:

```
 @admin.route('/admin/',methods=['GET'])
 def show():
     if not 'name' in session:
         return abort(403)
     return render_template('admin/index.html')
```

However, when I successfully login, flask merely prints the html from `admin/index.html` to the javascript console in both Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention the JS console, you're presumably making this request via Ajax. So your Ajax handler needs to do any redirection.

Comment: Can you give an example please? :)

Answer (score 0):

When you are requesting your form data from html, make sure that your button has the `type="submit"` instead of `type="button"`.  Changing this fixed the issue for me.

```
<form class="form-logIn" action="/logIn" method="post">
  <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
  <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

  <button id="btnLogIn" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block" type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
```